# How to insert a empty table by the result for select where and order by(PHP mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

In my php code,I want to *select* **num** and **transmiter** which is last record.And then  this two will be inserted into another table hpc_review.

```
insert into hpc_review (systemNum,handler) select num,transmiter from hpc_device where 
 translate='N' and transmiter=".$curr_people." order by num desc limit 1 ;
```

But it failed.When i choose the following two ways,it works fine;

```
insert into hpc_review (systemNum,handler) select num,transmiter from hpc_device order by 
 num desc limit 1 ;
insert into hpc_review (systemNum,handler) select num,transmiter from hpc_device 
 where translate='N' and transmiter=".$curr_people." ;
```

What is wrong with my code?
 who can help me ?

Comment: can you share your error message . i guess quotes problem . can you share your code as well as

Comment: You know that last_insert_id is session specific, right?

Comment: Do you getting value for this `select num,transmiter from hpc_device where 
 translate='N' and transmiter=".$curr_people." order by num desc limit 1` query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is intresting because it should be working. As i tried it,

it is working totally fine with where and order keyword.

as you didnt mention error i just guess
insert into hpc_review (systemNum,handler) select num,transmiter from hpc_device where translate='N' and transmiter='".$curr_people."' order by num desc limit 1 ;   (added single quotes in $curr_people varuable)

please share your mysql error message

Comment: transmiter='$curr_people',it works fine.I don't know why double quotes can't work fine